# Makefile.am: error: C++ source seen but 'CXX' is undefined

Tags: c, automake

I am writing a C library and program using the Autotools stack. It's a pure C code base and it did compile before.

Now I get the following error during my `autoreconf -v -f -i` step:

```
    Makefile.am: error: C++ source seen but 'CXX' is undefined
```

Just to state it again. There are no `.cc` or `.cxx` or `.cpp` files in the whole repository. The problem showed up when I started to add two further `.c` files to my library.

If I add `AC_PROG_CXX` to `configure.ac` everything works smoothly, but I don't want to introduce a C++ compiler as a dependency if its not needed.

```
info_TEXINFOS=foo.texi

ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS=-I m4

lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = lib/foo_vector.c \
    lib/sk.c\
    lib/foo_err.c\
    lib/foo_list.c\
    lib/foo_pair.c\
    lib/foo_string.c\
    lib/foo_reader.c\
    lib/foo_eval.cc
libfoo_la_CFLAGS = $(BDW_GC_CFLAGS) -I@abs_srcdir@/include -Wall
libfoo_la_LIBADD = $(BDW_GC_LIBS)

# version-info provided as current[:revision[:age]]
libfoo_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info 0:0:0

include_HEADERS = include/foo.h

SUBDIRS = . tests
```

Comment: What does your Makefile.am look like?  Have you re-run `autoreconf` to generate a clean configure script?

Comment: I would expect that error to occur when you run `automake`, which shouldn't be invoked by `configure`.

Comment: With "configure step" I meant `autoreconf  -v -f -i`.

Comment: also added Makefile.am to the question @WilliamPursell

Comment: `lib/foo_eval.cc` is the name of a C++ source file.

Comment: @AndrewHenle OMG I don't know how that typo escaped my eyes. Thanks.

Comment: @wirrbel Welcome to programming - where you stare at code for hours, unable to see your own typos.  But someone seeing your code for the first time sees them immediately.  Human brains literally don't "see" the errors they make.  That's one reason why walking away from your code for a few hours helps you spot mistakes.